# Element API: Get Entries Related to Category with Query Parameter

Tags: categories, plugin-elementapi, filter, query, category-filter

I'm using the [Element API Plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/element-api) to create an API, with which I want to get entries related to one category, but dynamically with the category set in the Url.

What I have so far in the **config/element-api.php**:

```
<?php

use craft\elements\Entry;
use craft\helpers\UrlHelper;

return [
  'endpoints' => [
    'api/projects.json' => function() {
      $projectCategory = \Craft::$app->request->getQueryParam('projectCategory');

      // dump for test purpose
      var_dump($projectCategory);

      return [
        'elementType' => Entry::class,
        'criteria' => [
          'section' => 'projects',
          'relatedTo' => "{$projectCategory}",
        ],
        'elementsPerPage' => 2,
        'transformer' => function(Entry $entry) {
          return [
            'title' => $entry->title,
            'url' => $entry->url,
            'jsonUrl' => UrlHelper::url("projects/{$entry->id}.json"),
            'thumbnail' => $entry->projectThumbnail,
            'description' => $entry->projectDescription,
            'credits' => $entry->projectCredits,
          ];
        },
      ];
    },
  ],
];
```

When I go to *http://domain.test/api/projects.json?projectCategory=category*, I get the right value dumped, but the relatedTo doesn't seem to work. I get zero entries, although there are some related to a specific category.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you passing the `projectCategory` parameter as a string or ID? In any case, the relatedTo parameter will receive a string in your code, which might trip up the query. If the parameter is passed as an ID, passing it as an integer instead of a string might be enough:

```php
'relatedTo' => (int) $projectCategory,
```

However, it might be cleaner to get the actual category element based on the ID and pass that to `relatedTo`. This will also allow you to check if the specified category actually exists (and optionally return an HTTP error for invalid parameters).

```php
$criteria = ['section' => 'projects'];
$projectCategory = \Craft::$app->request->getQueryParam('projectCategory');
// this assumes the category is passed as an ID
$category = \craft\elements\Category::find()->id((int) $projectCategory)->one();
if ($category) {
    $criteria['relatedTo'] = $category;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your reply. This works for me!